# Analogue to nuxt watchQuery in nuxt composition api

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-composition-api, asyncdata

I'm trying to migrate my app to vue3 syntax using @nuxtjs/composition-api

How I can restart useAsync method like it was in nuxt 2 with asyncData using watchQuery

Comment: `watch` or `refresh` may be interesting in your case: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/composables/use-async-data#type